# Will the value of the memory location following an array always be a 0?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've seen an example from Bjarne Stroustrup's 4th edition as follows:

```
char *p = "asdf";
for (; *p != 0; ++p)
    cout << "char: " << *p << endl;
```

To verify the end of the array, he's dereferencing the location first
and then, comparing with a zero. It worked.
I don't understand how it did.

1. What if the memory location following 'f' is other than zero (a garbage value). It should move even after the end of array.
2. Dereferencing a memory location, that is not constructed. Shouldn't it be crashed? Is it the null sequence character (\0) playing the part?

Comment: That can't possibly be an example from the book, since it's not even valid C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB const char aside, in what why is this not even valid?

Comment: @KerrekSB this is indeed valid.

Comment: @Borgleader, I assume the invalid conversion from `const char[N]` to `char *` is what he means.

Comment: It is valid, although it generates a warning, -Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings.

Comment: It's valid in C++03, not in C++11

Comment: @EricAppelt: It's invalid in C++11 or later. You get a warning rather than an error since you're compiling it as an obsolete dialect.

Comment: _"Shouldn't it be crashed?"_ **NO!** Breaking the rules of C and C++ does NOT mean you get a crash. You **might** get a crash, if you're lucky. But it might not crash and appear to work correctly (for now), or it might not crash and do something strange. It is a huge misunderstanding to think that if you do something wrong it will crash, and the corollary that if your program doesn't crash it is correct is also a huge misunderstanding.

Comment: @MikeSeymour well I was going to reply that Stroustrup's book predates C++11x so it is valid in context, but the 4th edition is advertised as being "Extensively rewritten to present the C++11 language", so you are right.

Comment: I don't think the example is taken verbatim from the book, because Stroustrup would write `char* p` not `char *p`. Anyway, the answer to the question in on page 176 where it explains string literals.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Right, and the question explicitly says "4th edition", so it refers to C++11...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in general, but in this specific case: Yes.

```
char *p = "asdf";
```

creates a `char*` to the string-literal "asdf", which is zero terminated. So the above code is safe.

This is different to e.g.

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
int *p = arr;
for (; *p != 0; ++p)
    cout << "int: " << *p << endl;
```

This does indeed invoke undefined behavior.

Btw, the conversion from string literals to `char*` is deprecated because attempting to change a string literal is also undefined behavior. You should use a `const char*` instead.

Comment: If the array is zero terminated, while finding the end of array, dereferencing this zero should be giving segmentation fault right? Why it is not?

Comment: @Neo The 0 is still part of the array. The literal `"Hi"` is something like `const char[] = {'H','i','\0'}`. You do not go out of bounds.

Answer (score 6):

> Will the value of the memory location following an array always be a 0?

No. Accessing that memory gives undefined behaviour; it might not be accessible, and any value you get from it is garbage.

However, a string literal like `"asdf"` denotes an array which has a zero-valued character at the end, as well as the characters specified by the literal; which is why this example, and C-style string-wrangling in general, works with string literals.

Note that, in modern C++, you'd need `const char *` rather than `char *`, since a string literal denotes a constant array.

Answer (score 2):

p is a pointer to a C style string. The compiler automatically adds an extra character and sets it to 0, null.

The null is used because it does not naturally occur in a string, and thus can be used as a sentinel value so you'll know when you reach the end of the string.

This is about the only case where this extra null happens, but compilers often perform little tricks like this to make life easier when performing common and mundane tasks. Call it syntactic sugar, a little helper that the compiler does for you to make life easier. Another example would be automatically generated trivial constructors and destructors.